# Affordable Medium Format SLR?

Tags: film, slr, medium-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Affordable Entry Level Medium Format](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/affordable-entry-level-medium-format)

Affordable medium format film SLR?